# dijit.registry.filter / dijit.registry.map won't iterate although dijit.registry is filled with registered widgets?

Tags: javascript, widget, registry, dojo

My Dojo app contains several widgets, which are all auto-registered in `dijit.registry` (an instance of [dijit.WidgetSet](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/WidgetSet)). I would like to make use of the `filter()` ([Link](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/WidgetSet#filter)) or `map()` ([Link](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/WidgetSet#map)) method to apply global changes to certain widgets filtered by a custom property pattern defined in the methods' callback functions.

Dumping the registry by `console.log(dijit.registry);` proves that it is filled with widgets:

[image: console.log(dijit.registry);]

Just to test the `filter()` method I did the following (exactly in the same scope as the above mentioned `console.log(dijit.registry);`):

```
var widgets = dijit.registry.filter(function(w, i) {
    return true;
});

console.log(widgets);
```

But I got the following output:

[image]

Similar behaviour when using the `map()` method:

```
var widgets = dijit.registry.map(function(w) {
    return w;
});

console.log(widgets);
```

... I get an empty array then.

What's going on here, what went wrong?

FYI: Making single `console.log(w);` inside the callback functions doesn't output anything, they even aren't invoked, meaning that `dijit.registry` isn't even being iterated by the two methods.

`console.log(dijit.registry._hash);` prints the object containing 12 properties (widgets). `for(var w in dijit.registry._hash) { /* ... */ }` doesn't work at all - it misteriously doesn't jump into the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet

```
var widgets = dijit.registry.filter(function(w, i) {
    return true;
});

console.log(widgets);
```

wasn't called inside a `dojo.addOnLoad(function() { /* ... */ });`, which led to the case created widgets weren't registered yet and couldn't be iterated via `dijit.registry.filter()`.

Comment: Unless you are using an old version of dojo, `dojo.ready` is a sexier alias to `addOnLoad`

Answer (score 1):

`dijit.registy.map` is Working Fine on My Machine<sup>TM</sup>, (Firefox 6).

You should try making a concrete example reproducing this. In the best case you find out its a typo or something like that and in the worst case we file a Dojo bug.

---

If all else fails, perhaps you can try hacking directly into the dijit.registry._hash object, iterating with a vanilla `for-in` loop. (I have no idea how safe this would be though)

Comment: `console.log(dijit.registry.filter(function(w, i) {
    return true;
}));` is returning all registered widgets for me (Chrome 13) as well.

Answer (score 1):

How are your widgets created?  Programmatically?  Declaratively?  Does dijit.byId('someId') correctly return your widgets?  The WidgetSet#filter function really doesn't do anything special (1.6.1 source):

```
filter: function(/*Function*/ filter, /* Object? */thisObj){
    // summary:
    //      Filter down this WidgetSet to a smaller new WidgetSet
    //      Works the same as `dojo.filter` and `dojo.NodeList.filter`
    //
    // filter:
    //      Callback function to test truthiness. Is passed the widget
    //      reference and the pseudo-index in the object.
    //
    // thisObj: Object?
    //      Option scope to use for the filter function.
    //
    // example:
    //      Arbitrary: select the odd widgets in this list
    //      |   dijit.registry.filter(function(w, i){
    //      |       return i % 2 == 0;
    //      |   }).forEach(function(w){ /* odd ones */ });

    thisObj = thisObj || dojo.global;
    var res = new dijit.WidgetSet(), i = 0, id;
    for(id in this._hash){
        var w = this._hash[id];
        if(filter.call(thisObj, w, i++, this._hash)){
            res.add(w);
        }
    }
    return res; // dijit.WidgetSet
},
```

Comment: The OP already figured out the problem. He was checking for the widgets before he created them. (And I think there is a time limit before he can accept his own answer) :/

Comment: oops, don't know how I missed that.